# How to drop table in Access if exists

Tags: c#, ms-access

I use C# and access db.
There is a statement in mysql for dropping table like below:

```
drop table if exists t_table
```

So do you know the similar statement for Access?

Comment: The SQL posted as answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985513/check-if-access-table-exists) should do what you need

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about SQL statment like this in Access.
You can, howewer, do one of the following:

- Try to drope table without checking if exists, catching exception (it should have specific code if no table was found) and ignoring it.
- Try to check in Access hidden table MSysObjects if table exists (with ADO however, it has no permission by default)
- Use a code like the one below (bad thing: dropping table do not return records affected):

  ```
  using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source=c:\myDatabase.mdb"))
  {
      conn.Open();

      string tableToDelete = "myTable";   //table name
      bool tableExists = false;

      DataTable dt = conn.GetSchema("tables");

      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
          if (row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() == tableToDelete)
          {
              tableExists = true;
              break;
          }
      }

      if (tableExists)
      {
          using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("DROP TABLE {0}", tableToDelete), conn))
          {
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              MessageBox.Show("Table deleted");
          }
      }
      else
          MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Table {0} not exists", tableToDelete));
  }
  ```