# Fastest Way To Delete Table (If Exists)

Tags: c#, ms-access, dao

I am using C# to connect to an access database and checking if a table exists in that database.  This is the syntax I am using, but for a few databases that have lots of tables in them it takes quite some time to execute.  Is their a faster way to do this as speed is the most important thing for this procedure?

```
string[] tableNames = new string[4] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };
for (int q = tableNames.GetLowerBound(0); q <= tableNames.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
{
  foreach (DAO.TableDef tabledef in dd.TableDefs)
  {
    string strtable = tableNames[q];
    if (tabledef.Name == strtable) { found = true; }
    if (found) { dd.TableDefs.Delete(strtable); } 
  }
}
```

For any future travelers who might stumble upon this, this was my final syntax that I used --- Exponentially faster!!!

Last EDIT --- I changed the `Execute` statement to be encapsulated in a `try/catch` block as if the table name that is listed in the array does not actually exist it will throw an error.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection oleconn = new   OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + PathToDatabase" + ".mdb;");
oleconn.Open();
string[] tableNames = new string[4] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };
for (int q = tableNames.GetLowerBound(0); q <= tableNames.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
{
  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DROP TABLE " + tableNames[q], oleconn);
  try { cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
  catch {}
}
oleconn.Close();
```

Comment: simply run `DROP TABLE [Tablename]` it will delete if exist otherwise does nothing

Comment: why can't you write a simple query that checks if the sysobject exist

Comment: @MethodMan the drop table already check if the entity exist so checking for it's existence before is double checking, hence not faster. Unless he plan to do something special if the table do or not exist the check is just slowing down the process.

Comment: I am aware of the @Franck but based on the unnecessary iteration is why I was asking that..

Comment: Are you aware that you don't reset the variable found to false? After the first match any subsequent table will be deleted.

Comment: @Steve you are correct, that was a good catch their.  Thank you!

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that uses T-SQL code and will not work with Access SQL?

Comment: @GordThompson just deselected.  I initially hit that one as that was the route I was going to go.  Then it was compile error after compile error so I went another route.  Unselected.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the loops (pseudo code):

```
foreach (DAO.TableDef tabledef in dd.TableDefs)
{
  if (tabledef.Name in tablearray )
  { 
    dd.TableDefs.Delete(strtable); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of checking in C# application run following query with your ado.net.

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'mytablename', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE 'mytablename'
```

Because it will load meta data when you use ado.net instead of that execute simple query with execute non query.

Comment: I was not aware that OBJECT_ID and that syntax could be used against an MS-Access database. But given the fact that the poster accepted your answer then I am probably wrong.

Comment: (cc: @Steve ) This is T-SQL code. It will not work with Access SQL.

Comment: @GordThompson Uhm as suspected

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Drop Table` for deleting table..
and its syntax is

```
   if exists (select * from login where name = 'prishu' and pass='prishu')
    drop table login
```

for more information use this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-table.html)

check [this link also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985513/check-if-access-table-exists)

Comment: We are talking of an MS-Access database. Did you try that syntax?