# Ms Access - VBA - ADO conflict

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

In my access VBA code (Access Professional Plus 2021), I simply want to check if a table exists with the line :

If Not DBEngine(0).TableExists("MyTable") Then...

I wanted to, hence, add the component Microsoft ADO so that it accepts the method TableExists(), but I get a conflict statement although I only have the following components:

- Visual Basic Application
- Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Access Database Engine Library
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

How can I overcome this problem?
Generally, I jsut want to be able to import csv files, manipulate them a little and export them back to a drive. Thanks in advance

-

Comment: And what is the conflict statement?

Comment: I think adding ADO to an access application just to check if a table exists is overkill. Have a look to the various proposed methods here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985513/check-if-access-table-exists